# Getting all the settings for a plugin

Tags: settings-api, options

Looking at the Settings API and you can register new setting using register_setting() but I can't find a way of getting all the settings for a certain plugin.

Let's say I want to get a list with all settings for pluginA, how would you do it?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the **2nd parameter** of `register_setting()` is actually the `option_name` of `options` table. If you are putting multiple fields under a same setting, the `option_value` would be an array, otherwise would be a string. And you can get each of those `register_setting` very simply by putting `get_option('option_name')`

Answer (score 1):

Setting aren't registered in the database by plugin, though a plugin should be using an identifying prefix. That is, there is no specific queryable cross-linking in the database between plugin and setting. The only way to way to pull all settings for a plugin is to know what keys the plugin has used to save those settings.

Comment: any suggestion how do I get to know what keys the plugin has used to save those settings? I mean, I could open the plugin and read it, but I want to be able to do it automatically so how could I write code that reads which keys have been used to save the settings?

Comment: find all the files of that plugin for string like `register_setting` if the plugin uses Settings API.

Comment: Look at the plugin source. Read through the code. That's it. I guess you could `grep` for `register_setting` or `update_option`... things like that.

Comment: "... how could I write code that reads which keys..." -- your code will have to open the plugin source and read it, which is a complex project. There is no other way besides reading the plugin code.